# Webpack paths issue with es6

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack

I have a structure like this but am having an error when trying to run webpack

```
    /app
      /main.js
      /foo.js
    /dist
    index.html ( uses <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>)
    webpackconfig.js
```

in main.js:

```
import foo from './foo'

var foo = new foo()
```

foo.js:

```
export class foo {
  constructor() {
    loadScript("//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.4.0.min.js", init());
  }
}
```

webpackconfig.js

My config:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/app",
  entry: "./main.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devtool: "#source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // Transpile any JavaScript file:
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    // you can now require('file') instead of require('file.js')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  }
}
```

but I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./main.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'foo'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `webpack` try to load `foo` from `node_modules` directory.
You have to specify the path of your module like this:

```
import foo from './foo'
```

Comment: foo.js:

export class foo { etc}

Comment: export default class foo ;)

Comment: is still get Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "foo", I've added the index to the diagram above which is what loads bundle.js

Comment: Maybe I could email you my simple project?